# Peebee Repercussions of Loyalty Mission on Romance

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

*spoilers*

In the last mission in Peebee's series of loyalty missions, if I take the shot in the quick-time event, am I still able to successfully romance Peebee? There does not seem to be a consensus in the walkthroughs I've found, and if I need to redo the mission, I want to do it before I've played 30 more hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and committed. A bit later, a cut scene with Peebee confirmed that I can still romance her. Hitting the QTE doesn't ruin your chances with Peebee.